# How to add ICU library to project?

Tags: cmake, icu

Help me please. I would like to add ICU library to my project. My cmake version is 2.8.12.2.

There is CMakeLists.txt

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
>
> project(test1)
>
> set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}) 
>  set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
>   /usr/bin/g++) 
> set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
>   -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++11 -Wall")
>
> find_package(Boost 1.54.0 COMPONENTS filesystem system regex
>   unit_test_framework REQUIRED) 
> find_package(ICU 52.0 REQUIRED )
>
> include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
>   
> link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
>
> add_executable(test1 src/dictionary.cpp 
>         src/main.cpp
>         ) 
>  target_link_libraries( test1 ${Boost_LIBRARIES} pthread
>         )

I have installed ICU libraries: libicu-dev, libicu-dev:i386, libicu52, libicu52:i386, libicu52-dbg:i386

But once I run CMake, I get the following error message:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindICU.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "ICU", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ICU" (requested
  version 52.1) with any of the following names:

    ICUConfig.cmake
    icu-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ICU" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "ICU_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "ICU" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

What should I do? Help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was solved by adding the file FindICU.cmake at top of the project directory from http://github.com/julp/FindICU.cmake

Comment: Since version 3.7.0, [CMake comes with a packaged `FindICU.cmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindICU.html#module:FindICU), which however works differently to the one by julp (i.e. is incompatible).

Comment: @DevSolar, on my macbook with homebrew installed icu4c, it's not working.

Comment: @linrongbin This comment is hardly the place to debug the issue; perhaps ask a separate question?

Answer (score 10):

Using CMake 3.13.

```
add_executable(myapp
    main.cpp
)

# ICU Components Reference:
# https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindICU.html
# ICU components = data, i18n, io, le, lx, test, tu and uc.

find_package(ICU 61.0 COMPONENTS uc i18n REQUIRED)

# Link using the imported target names (ICU::uc, ICU::i18n, etc.)

target_link_libraries(myapp ICU::uc ICU::i18n)
```

Note: This wouldn't work unless I specifically listed the components in the find_package statement.

Comment: "Note: This wouldn't work unless I specifically listed the components in the find_package statement." You, sir, are a life-saver!

Answer (score 4):

If ICU library is **required**, use:

```
find_package(ICU REQUIRED components...)
target_link_libraries(lab1 ${ICU_LIBRARIES})
```

If it's **optional**, use:

```
find_package(ICU COMPONENTS components...)
target_link_libraries(lab1 ${ICU_LIBRARIES})
```

Where *components...* is a list of ICU library components that can be found [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindICU.html).
***INSERT* these lines *ONLY AFTER* *add_executable* command!**

Answer (score 0):

It is all about including the headers and linking the libraries. For small projects, you can probably just do, (assume you already have ICU properly installed, and can be run manually)

```
include_directories(${ICU_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${ICU_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_executable(test1 src/dictionary.cpp src/main.cpp ) 
target_link_libraries(test1 ${ICU_LIBRARIES})
```

You can use below to print the info when you run "cmake" to check if cmake finds the correct path.

```
MESSAGE("ICU_INCLUDE_DIRS: " ${ICU_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

The cmake version I am using is 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

For my case with Cmake version: 3.22

I used

```
find_package(ICU 70.1 COMPONENTS uc REQUIRED)
..
..
target_link_libraries(
    ${LIBRARY_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    ..
    ..
    ICU::uc
    ..
)
```

which helped removing any undefined symbols.